# React createElement type should not be null/ Uncaught Invariant Violation

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to render a multi-select component within a nav bar but am coming back with these errors:

> warning.js:36Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null,
>   undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM
>   elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render
>   method of `EventsFilters`.
>
> invariant.js:38 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid:
>   expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
>   composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of
>   `EventsFilters`.

Pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Filter Code:

```jsx
import React from 'react';

//Event Types Filter
class EventsFilters extends React.Component {
  //Define react properties
  static propTypes: {
    setLocalStorage: 'jjj',
    selectedFilters: 'sds',
  }

render() {

var SelectList = React.SelectList;
var items = [
  {id: 0, name: 'Workflow Event'},
  {id: 1, name: 'Dev Event'},
];

//Event Workflow Select List
var EventsWorkflowFilters = (
<div>
  <SelectList
          textField='name'
          valueField='id'
          className='selectlist-unstyled list-inline filter-list'
          defaultValue={[0]}
          data={items}
          multiple="true" />
</div>
)



return(EventsWorkflowFilters)

}}

export default EventsFilters;
```

Comment: React.SelectList is probably undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React does not provide a SelectList component so your `SelectList` variable is `undefined`, you need to do it yourself or check on npm if someone already has. For example you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select and check the documentation to see how to use it.

Hope this help